# Execute a javascript from within codeigniter using the console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to execute a dom ready javascript function from within codeigniter, I know how to do it -regular and usual way- using a view, but now I need to do it using the console, as when you usually run a `php index.php controller method parameter_A parameter_B...` from the console, my javascript function itself contains an ajax function as part of its definition, i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    function envia_mail_ajax(numero, form_data,ruta){   
    var iddiv="#mail_"+numero;
    window.setTimeout( 
    function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('emailmasivo'); ?>/" +ruta+ "/" +numero, 
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(html){
            $( iddiv ).append(html.mensaje+"\n"+'<br />');
        }   
    });
}, 600);    
}
    var hola="hola";
    var cuenta_id=<?php echo $id_cuenta; ?>;

    <?php 
        echo $lista_mails;
    ?>

    if( correos_e.length==0)
        window.close();
    j=0;
    for (i=<?php    echo $ini;  ?>; i<(correos_e.length);i++){
        if ( correos_e[i] != undefined ){
            j=j+1;
            str_tmp = '<div id="mail_'+i+'">'+correos_e[i]+
                    '<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/ajax-loader.gif"  />'+'</div>'+"\n";
            console.log(str_tmp);
            $('#resultado_envio').append( str_tmp );
            envia_mail_ajax(i,
    {para:correos_e[i],id_masivos:id_masivos_e[i],id_mat_referencia:id_mat_referencia_e[i],
            id_tipouser:id_tipouser_e[i],nombre:nombres_e[i], sexo:sexos_e[i], matricula:matriculas_e[i], passa:passa_e[i],id_cuenta:cuenta_id},
                "<?php echo $r_ajax; ?>");              
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

as you can see, there´s no problem in using a view (this code is located in a view!), but, how can make the javascript run when using the console to run the whole program using the same controller, method and parameters used in the browser-view version? thanx i.a.

Comment: you can't. there's no JS engine when you're running PHP at the command line.

Comment: Yeah man you can't call a HTML/JS view file from the Command Line Interface, it will just output the lot as text

Comment: hmm.. what console are you referring to, the browser's developer tools console?

Comment: @BrettCaswell nop, the usual system console/terminal in *nix, linux, OS X  boxes.

Comment: Otherwise, how could I overcome that 'barrier' in order to run my program from the terminal?